# Which sort of soy milk makers automate the most steps?

Tags: dairy-substitutes, soy

Making soymilk (or nut milk) by hand calls for lots of blending, cooking and straining.

Which machines or machine categories automate most of the steps? Are there non-industrial (i.e. consumer market) versions of a fully automated machine?

Answer (score 2):

The Vitamix can do it without cooking (you soak over-night), but you'll need to strain it yourself if you don't want any sediment. We use a hand strainer. It's not real fine like what you would find in a coffee maker, but it works for us. Some people use a cloth.

This is a heavy-duty machine for the commercial market.

Here is a link to their Almond Milk recipe:  https://www.vitamix.com/recipes/almond-milk/s-series/variable-speed/20-ounce-container

Comment: Please edit your comment to make it brand-agnostic. Change "Vitamix" to "blender or food processor" and maybe add the power needed (watts) to adequately blend soy beans.

Comment: @ecc - I'm not sure power is enough. I own two blenders and the other (my goal is not to bash or unobjectively promote a particular device/brand) just doesn't work as well. I think the blades and possibly their design are factors as well.